# What is the Rust equivalent to Intel's tbb::concurrent_queue?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, concurrent-queue, rust-crates

I am looking for an equivalent of the [`concurrent_queue`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506081) from Intel's [tbb](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) module in Rust. I have found some crates:

1. [multiqueue](https://github.com/schets/multiqueue)
2. [two-lock-queue](https://github.com/carllerche/two-lock-queue)
3. [crossbeam-deque](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam-deque)

and even

4. [futures-pool](https://github.com/carllerche/futures-pool)
5. [thread-pool](https://github.com/carllerche/thread-pool)

I feel like they are all doing similar things, however in their docs it seems that they are using different algorithms for the implementation.

Though I don't know a lot about programming in C++, I am pretty sure that tbb's `concurrent_queue` is a very fast MPMC queue implementation. You cannot be close to that performance if you only wrap a queue container in a `Mutex` (which is tested by one of my friends).

Since the efficiency (both latency and throughput) is the main thing I care about, what should I use in Rust? The queue could be either bounded or unbounded and I probably need Acquire-Release ordering.

Comment: Bounded or unbounded? And what kind of ordering guarantees do you need? Do you care about latency or only throughput?

Comment: Could be bounded or unbounded. I probably need Acquire-Release ordering if it is what you asked. And i care about latency as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`crossbeam::sync::MsQueue`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.2/crossbeam/sync/struct.MsQueue.html) and the [`crossbeam::sync::SegQueue`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.2/crossbeam/sync/struct.SegQueue.html) from the crossbeam crate have the same capabilities as the [concurrent_queue](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506081) you linked.

They are lock free queues that can be used in a non blocking way with [`push`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.2/crossbeam/sync/struct.MsQueue.html#method.push) and [`try_pop`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.2/crossbeam/sync/struct.MsQueue.html#method.try_pop).

[This benchmark](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2015/08/27/epoch/#benchmarks) indicates that `SegQueue` is faster than `MsQueue`, but that may still depend on your use case.